# Is the existence of a sole particle in an hypothetical infinite empty space explicitly forbidden by QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, approximations

Suppose the universe is completely empty with one sole particle trapped in it. To simplify, I will only be looking at the one dimensional case. However, all arguments are applicable for three dimensions. The solution of the  Schrödinger equation $\hat{H} \psi = E \psi $ with  $\hat{H} = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}$ and $\quad \hat{p} = -i\hbar \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}$   for a free particle ($V=0$) is then given by $\psi(x,t)=A\exp{i(kx-wt)}$ with constants $w=\frac{E}{\hbar}$ and $E=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}$ which can easily be shown. In order to meet the criteria of QM, $\langle \psi|\psi\rangle$ needs to be normalized (=1). If that is not possible, there is no way such a quantity can be interpreted as a probability density. However, if you try to normalize the density you will find:

\begin{align*}
\langle\psi|\psi\rangle
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi \psi^* dx \\
&= |A|^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp{i(kx-wt)} \exp{-i(kx-wt)}\mathrm dx \\
&=|A|^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1\cdot\mathrm dx\\
&=\infty\,.
\end{align*}

Thus, it is not possible to find said normalization. Asking around, I found that such cases are normally treated as an approximation of a very wide (yet finite) potential well, or in the 3-dimensional case, a box. This allows a fairly simple solution which can be normalized. However it only represents an **approximation**. In a rigorous point of view there exist no such solutions which satisfy the postulates of Quantum Mechanics. Does that mean that the laws of QM fundamentally prohibit a infinite empty universe with only one sole particle trapped in it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That the eigenfunctions of the free Hamiltonian $H\propto p^2$ are not actually normalizable due to its completely continuous spectrum and therefore *cannot be actual quantum states* is well-known, although rarely suitably emphasized. (See e.g. [Why are eigenfunctions which correspond to discrete/continuous eigenvalue spectra guaranteed to be normalizable/non-normalizable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68639/50583) and [Rigged Hilbert space and QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43515/50583) for some further reading)

But this doesn't mean no free particles exist, it just means that there are no momentum eigenstates for them. E.g. for any smooth compactly supported function $f$, we have that $\psi(x) = \int f(p)\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}px}\mathrm{d}p$ is normalizable (because in Fourier space, its square integral is just $\int \lvert f(p)\rvert^2\mathrm{d}p$, which is certainly finite), and this is a perfectly fine wavefunction for a perfectly fine state - it just isn't an eigenstate of the time evolution, it's a "smooth superposition" of them. We could just have taken $f$ as a wavefunction directly, which would also be fine, but this way $\psi$ is what one calls a "wavepacket", at least for suitably narrow $f$.