# How does the wave function of free particle $\psi(x,t)=A\exp \{ i(kx-\omega t)\}$ satisfy normalisation condition?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, probability, normalization

I am confused about the wave function of a free particle

$$\psi(x,t)=A\exp \{ i(kx-\omega t)\}$$

How does this satisfy the normalization condition? Since this corresponds to a plane wave, what meaning does the probability have?

Comment: It does not satisfy it, and therefore it does not represent a physical state.

Comment: Then why do we use it?

Comment: Like for many other things in physics, it is a useful idealization.

Comment: Also, a *superposition* of plane waves can represent a physical state.

Comment: Hi John. Also see ACuriousMind's characteristically excellent answer to [Is the existence of a sole particle in an hypothetical infinite empty space explicitly forbidden by QM?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/253716/is-the-existence-of-a-sole-particle-in-an-hypothetical-infinite-empty-space-expl)

Answer (score 0):

It does NOT satisfy the usual normalization condition.  The plane wave has the same probability density everywhere.  The normalization of plane waves requires the introduction of $\delta$-functions.

Comment: Then why are we using it?

Comment: The introduction of the $\delta$ function allows you to introduce some kind of "orthogonality condition", but no normalization.