# Bound state and discreteness

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, discrete

The solution of Schrodinger equation in finite square well gives discrete energies in the bound states, but the energy is not discrete in case of scattering state. What is the physical reason behind this?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39208/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65636/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68639/2451 and links therein.

Comment: What definition of scattering state do you use?

Comment: @DanielC for scattering state,a particle has energy more than the energy at infinity