# Geometric description of canonical commutation relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, geometry, phase-space

Does there exist any geometrical description of canonical commutation relation (CCR) of quantum mechanics
$$[\hat{x},\hat{p}] = i \hbar \, ,$$
e.g. in phase space?

The commutator, along with the normalization condition, leads to the discretization of energy of a bound system, so does there exist some kind of phase space representation as in [this reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BggT4.jpg) which would tell me why and how exactly using the CCR actually leads to the discretization of energy? I would like to avoid going for the Wigner representation (WR) because, if I remember correctly, the RW has commuting functions in phase space. While we're at it, does the phase space of a quantum system has to do anything with connes noncommutative geometry since $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ do not commute so we cannot do something like [this reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqDlK.png) as we do in classical mechanics?

Comment: You might take a look at "geometric quantization" (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_quantization)

Comment: In coordinate space, where $\hat p=-i\hbar ~\partial_x$, this is a geometric triviality, $[x,\partial_x]=1$. This is not what you are seeking, is it?

Comment: For the peculiar telltale topology and geometry of quantum flows in phase space, a good start is [Kakofengitis, Oliva, & Steuernagel 2017](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.95.022127).

Comment: The Wigner picture is completely equivalent to the standard Hilbert space one, so, obviously, Connes' construction can *also* be described in the Wigner picture. In fact, it is in this picture that you find the fuzzed-up profiles of your 2nd picture. In general, nontrivial, cases, the Steuernagel et al ref I adduced explains just that!

Comment: Are you asking about [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33668/why-are-the-inner-products-of-the-eigenfunctions-of-an-operator-with-a-discrete)?

Comment: I remember reading once that in stochastic processes, there's a notion of $x$ and $p$ that are generators of translation in position and momentum that have $[x, p] = 1$. It's note quite the same as in quantum mechanics, but the similarity showing up in another context where there's randomness seems interesting.